# UIButton not showing highlight when touched

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am trying to highlight my UIButton with a custom UIColor light grey and make the text go white. However, I am not sure how to do this; this is how far I have gotten with creating the UIButton.

```
cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, calculatorView.frame.size.height-55, 100.0, 45.0);
    [cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(calculateMethod:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [[cancelButton titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Super-text" size:20.0]];
    [cancelButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To get the white text on highlight just do:

```
[cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor]
                       forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

To get the background to change you need to either do setBackgroundImage:forState: and use a UIImage with the pattern color, or subclass UIButton and set the appropriate background color in the setHighlight: method.

EDIT: Swift 2.x version

```
cancelButton.setTitleColor(.whiteColor(), forState: Highlighted)
```

EDIT: Swift 3.0 version

```
cancelButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .highlighted)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create an image to fill in the background with color.

```
[cancelButton setBackgroundImage:[self setBackgroundImageByColor:[UIColor blueColor] withFrame:cancelButton.frame cornerRadius:0] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

This method builds an image the size of the button with a solid background of the color *backgroundColor*.

```
-(UIImage *)setBackgroundImageByColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor withFrame:(CGRect )rect cornerRadius:(float)radius{

    UIView *tcv = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [tcv setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];

    CGSize gcSize = tcv.frame.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gcSize);
    [tcv.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, image.scale);
    const CGRect RECT = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);;
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:RECT cornerRadius:radius] addClip];
    [image drawInRect:RECT];
    UIImage* imageNew = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return imageNew;
}
```

Comment: The highest voted answer (and accepted answer) sets the text, but this answer really provides a solution to highlighting the entire button when selected. I've added some edits to clarify (and fixed spelling). This works for me on a button with both text and an image.

Comment: Not work. The button is missing when pressing. My button is blue, and I've set the background color to gray, but not work

Answer (score 3):

I know you wanted a white highlight color, but for anyone else that doesn't care specifically what color the highlight is, just **switch the button type to System** (in the Attribute Inspector). The nice thing is that you can still use custom fonts, colors, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use [titleColor:forState:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/titleColorForState%3a) to set the color of text on selection/highlight/disable for the respective [states](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlState).

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @nitin kachhadiya is very good, but I tweaked it, simplified it, and made it a category of UIButton. Add these two files to your project. Then to choose the color you want to set:

```
[button setHighlightedColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

**UIButton+FJHighlighted.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIButton (FJHighlighted)

- (void)setHighlightedColor:(UIColor *)highlightColor;

@end
```

**UIButton+FJHighlighted.m**

```
#import "UIButton+FJHighlighted.h"

@implementation UIButton (FJHighlighted)

- (void)setHighlightedColor:(UIColor *)highlightColor {
    [self setBackgroundImage:[self setBackgroundImageByColor:highlightColor cornerRadius:0]
                    forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}

- (UIImage *)setBackgroundImageByColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor cornerRadius:(float)radius {
    UIView *tcv = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    [tcv setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];

    CGSize gcSize = tcv.frame.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gcSize);
    [tcv.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, image.scale);
    const CGRect RECT = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);;
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:RECT cornerRadius:radius] addClip];
    [image drawInRect:RECT];
    UIImage *imageNew = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return imageNew;
}

@end
```